# Having 2 different SHA1 for same android package

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

We are two guys developing an android app, but when generating our SHA-1 to access the google map api, we get 2 different SHA-1. Is it possible to add two different SHA-1 but having the same package and use the same API-KEY?

Do I have to give him my debug key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, very much possible. You can generate several Map API keys with different SHA-1 fingerprints(from different machines) for the same app(or package).

And no, you don't have to provide him the debug.keystore file. The debug keystore he's using will work fine once you give him another map key by using his machine's SHA-1 fingerprint.

Comment: I added an edit on my post, forgot it was about the API-KEY given by google. Can we use the same API-KEY?

Comment: No you can't. Since you and the other guy are using different machine (means different SHA-1 fingerprints) and each of you have debug keystore of your own, so generating two Map API keys for each of you would be the right away.

Comment: Is it possible to use a configuration file instead of putting the key in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: You can put all your keys in string.xml and refer it to your manifest file according to your machine.

Comment: @Lorac If the answer meets your inquiries please accept the answer.